# Reusing existing linked list API implementation

Tags: c, linux

I have in the existing source base, linked list implementation(adding node, insertion, deletion , traversal) for the following structure:

```
typedef struct tagDirInfo
{
  char *pdirName;
  struct tagDirInfo *__next;
  struct tagDirInfo *__prev;
}DIR_HEADER;
```

Lets assume that char* pdirName points to the data part 
I want to form a wrap up for the data part and reuse the existing APIs and so that, the new linked list structure has the data part as:

```
typedef struct printJob
{
  char labelName[BUF_LEN];
  int priStatus;
  time_t time_stamp;
}PRINTJOB;
```

I think if I do something like:

```
PRINTJOB newJob;
/* Fill in newJob structure */
DIR_HEADER *newNode;
newNode->pdirName = (char*)newJob;
newNode->__next = NULL;
newNode->__prev = NULL;
```

Doing so, will fill in the linked list structure.

But how can I access labelName data field through pdirName field of the linked list structure?

Answer (score 1):

You should use templates (if you could use c++).

```
char* Labelname = ((PRINTJOB*) newNode->pdirName)->labelName;
```

By the way, "`newJob`" should be of type `PRINTJOB*` not `PRINTJOB`.

A better solution would be following:

```
typedef struct _LINKED_LIST {
  struct _LINKED_LIST *_Next;
  struct _LINKED_LIST *_Prev;
} LINKED_LIST;

typedef struct {
    LINKED_LIST List;
    char labelName[BUF_LEN];
    int priStatus;
    time_t time_stamp;
} MY_LINKED_LIST_DATA;

MY_LINKED_LIST_DATA* MyData = (MY_LINKED_LIST_DATA*) 
malloc(sizeof(MY_LINKED_LIST_DATA));
MyData->List->_Next = NULL;
MyData->List->_Prev = NULL;
```

Your data always contains linked list specific fields `_Next` and `_Prev`.

Comment: Nah, its okay, by declaring it as PRINTJOB, he doesn't have to `malloc()` or `calloc()` it

Comment: You are right, but then he has to use &newJob. However stack addresses are going out of scope as soon as he leaves the sub routine. I think this is usually not intended, malloc is safer here.

Comment: True, that. Cheers mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want do something like :

```
printf("labelName : %s\n", ((PRINTJOB *)(newNode->pdirName))->labelName);
```

However, your code have one mistake! To correct it:

Change

> newNode->pdirName = (char*)newJob;

to

> newNode->pdirName = (char*)&newJob;

Comment: Thanks @isayme
I was thinking of something like:
char* get_labelName( DIR_HEADER *node )

{

    PRINTJOB *job;

    job = (PRINTJOB *)(node->pdirName);

    return job->labelName;

}

But whatever you have suggested seems to minimise code and func calls.. :)